# Making a drawn rectangle disappear for pygame

Tags: python

I am only quite new to Python only been working on the Introduction Netacad course for about 4 weeks now and I am having trouble with an lab exercise given to me by my lecturer.

Using a prebuilt pygame file it asks to add in lines of code to add left and right movement upon left and right keydown evens, up and down, and increase speed and decrease for which ive already completed. I am having trouble with the final task which asks:

Add a feature to make player1 sprite visible/invisible when the space bar is pressed.

So i figure this must just be another keydown event/listener but what exactly is the if statement outcome to make my already drawn rectangle sprite disappear and reappear.

This is my code below and sorry if i havent been clear with this im quite new to this language and only ever done C# intro before.

```
import pygame  # accesses pygame files
import sys  # to communicate with windows

# game setup ################ only runs once
pygame.init()  # starts the game engine
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # creates clock to limit frames per second
FPS = 60  # sets max speed of main loop
SCREENSIZE = SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT = 1000, 800  # sets size of screen/window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE)  # creates window and game screen
# set variables for colors RGB (0-255)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)

gameState = "running"  # controls which state the games is in
player1XPos = 100 #Variable for x axes position of player 1
player1YPos = 100 #Variable for Y axis position
player1Direction = ""
player1Speed = 5
player1Visible
# game loop #################### runs 60 times a second!
# your code starts here ##############################
while gameState != "exit":  # game loop - note:  everything in the mainloop is indented one tab
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # get user interaction events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # tests if window's X (close) has been clicked
            gameState = "exit"  # causes exit of game loop
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                #Decreases playerYPos -5 on the X axis
                player1Direction = "left"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                #Inrceases playerYPos +5 on the Y Axis
                player1Direction = "right"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                #player1XPos Decreases playerxPos -5 on the X axis
                player1Direction = "up"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                #player1YPos Inrceases playeryPos +5 on the Y axis
                player1Direction = "down"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player1Speed= player1Speed / 2
                #Decrease movement speed player1Speed of movement
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                player1Speed= player1Speed * 2
                #Increase movement speed player1Speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                
                
                
  
                

    # Player 1 Event handler code now...
    if player1Direction =="up":
        player1YPos = player1YPos - player1Speed
        #Increases the player1 rectangle up on the Y axis
    elif player1Direction =="down":
        player1YPos = player1YPos + player1Speed
        #Decreases the player1 rectangle on Y Axis
    if player1Direction =="left":
        player1XPos = player1XPos - player1Speed
        #Moves the player1Pos to the left by decreasing X Pos by the value of player1Speed
        #which is 5
    elif player1Direction =="right":
        player1XPos = player1XPos + player1Speed
        #Moves player1Pos rectangle to the right by increasing player1XPos X axis position
        #by the value of player1Speed
    

      

    screen.fill(black)
    player1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (player1XPos, player1YPos, 80, 80))
    




    # your code ends here ###############################
    pygame.display.flip()  # transfers build screen to human visable screen
    clock.tick(FPS)  # limits game to frame per second, FPS value

# out of game loop ###############
print("The game has closed")  # notifies user the game has ended
pygame.quit()   # stops the game engine
sys.exit()  # close operating system window
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to conditionally draw the player 1 sprite only if player 1 is visible. Every time when the space is pressed, the value of player1Visible changes to the opposite value.

```
import pygame  # accesses pygame files
import sys  # to communicate with windows

# game setup ################ only runs once
pygame.init()  # starts the game engine
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # creates clock to limit frames per second
FPS = 60  # sets max speed of main loop
SCREENSIZE = SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT = 1000, 800  # sets size of screen/window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE)  # creates window and game screen
# set variables for colors RGB (0-255)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)

gameState = "running"  # controls which state the games is in
player1XPos = 100 #Variable for x axes position of player 1
player1YPos = 100 #Variable for Y axis position
player1Direction = ""
player1Speed = 5
player1Visible = True
# game loop #################### runs 60 times a second!
# your code starts here ##############################
while gameState != "exit":  # game loop - note:  everything in the mainloop is indented one tab
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # get user interaction events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # tests if window's X (close) has been clicked
            gameState = "exit"  # causes exit of game loop
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                #Decreases playerYPos -5 on the X axis
                player1Direction = "left"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                #Inrceases playerYPos +5 on the Y Axis
                player1Direction = "right"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                #player1XPos Decreases playerxPos -5 on the X axis
                player1Direction = "up"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                #player1YPos Inrceases playeryPos +5 on the Y axis
                player1Direction = "down"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player1Speed= player1Speed / 2
                #Decrease movement speed player1Speed of movement
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                player1Speed= player1Speed * 2
                #Increase movement speed player1Speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player1Visible = not player1Visible        
  
                
    # Player 1 Event handler code now...
    if player1Direction =="up":
        player1YPos = player1YPos - player1Speed
        #Increases the player1 rectangle up on the Y axis
    elif player1Direction =="down":
        player1YPos = player1YPos + player1Speed
        #Decreases the player1 rectangle on Y Axis
    if player1Direction =="left":
        player1XPos = player1XPos - player1Speed
        #Moves the player1Pos to the left by decreasing X Pos by the value of player1Speed
        #which is 5
    elif player1Direction =="right":
        player1XPos = player1XPos + player1Speed
        #Moves player1Pos rectangle to the right by increasing player1XPos X axis position
        #by the value of player1Speed
      

    screen.fill(black)
    if player1Visible:
        player1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (player1XPos, player1YPos, 80, 80))


    # your code ends here ###############################
    pygame.display.flip()  # transfers build screen to human visable screen
    clock.tick(FPS)  # limits game to frame per second, FPS value

# out of game loop ###############
print("The game has closed")  # notifies user the game has ended
pygame.quit()   # stops the game engine
sys.exit()  # close operating system window
```

Comment: Thankyou so much this is exactly what i need

Comment: @Smitty90r great, could you please accept the answer in that case?

Comment: Oh whoops sorry @mbostic lol im noob as thanks again